# programmatically call already set UIBarButtonItem action

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am creating what I believe will be a really sweet automated testing suite for iOS.  However, I need to be able to call a previously set action for any given UIBarButtonItem.  I can tell from the debugger that I am really dealing with a UIButton but weeks of trying different ways of getting to that action have failed.  If anyone can figure out how to call that selector I would be most pleased.

Again I don't want to set an action I want to call an action someone else has already set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like following.

```
for rightButton in navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems ?? [] {
    if let target = rightButton.target,
        let selector = rightButton.action {
        target.perform(selector)
    }
}
```

It currently loop through the right bar button items, and for each item it gather the `target` and the `selector`. If they are set already, then just execute that `selector` upon that `target`.

You can do it for left bar button items.